# Bindig issue in react using ant design framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, mern, ant-design-pro

I am making CRUD application on react Using ant design, i am using axios to get data from nodejs server

Here is the code of Table

```
 <Table columns={columns} dataSource={dataSource} />
```

here is the useState where i am saving my data

```
 const [dataSource,SetDataSource] = useState([])
```

here is the useEffect for fetching data

```
 useEffect(() => {

    const load = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/stock/list')
            const myData = await res.json();
            const check = myData.data;
            console.log(check)
            SetDataSource(check)
            console.log(dataSource)
            // console.log(myData.data)
            // console.log(allItems);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    load()
}, []
)
```

here are columns using in my table

```
 const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Item Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: '1',
      render: text => <a>{text}</a>,
    },
    {
      title: 'Category',
      dataIndex: 'Category',
      key: '2',
    },
    {
      title: 'Item Price',
      dataIndex: 'Item_Price',
      key: '3',
    },
    {
      title: 'Item Amount',
      dataIndex: 'Item_Amount',
      key: '4',
    },

    {
      title: 'Action',
      key: '5',
      render: (record) => {
        return(
          <>
          <EditOutlined onClick={()=>{
            onEditItems(record)
          }}/>
          <DeleteOutlined onClick={()=>{
            onDeleteItems(record)
          }} style={{color:"red", marginLeft:12}}/>
            </>
        );
        }
    },
  ];
```

here are items showing in my console log
[image]

here is my screen where i have to display my records
[image]

Comment: maybe im missing something, but your `dataIndex` properties don't align with the properties in your response object? e.g. `Item_Amount` !== `itemPrice`

Comment: thanks lot now it's working

Answer (score 0):

dataIndex must be same as the property name in the response. for example for first column dataIndex should be 'itemName' which is property from the response.

So you columns object will be as follow

```
const columns = [
{
  title: 'Item Name',
  dataIndex: 'itemName',
  key: '1',
  render: text => <a>{text}</a>,
},
{
  title: 'Category',
  dataIndex: 'itemCategory',
  key: '2',
},
{
  title: 'Item Price',
  dataIndex: 'itemPrice',
  key: '3',
},
{
  title: 'Item Amount',
  dataIndex: 'stockAmount',
  key: '4',
},

{
  title: 'Action',
  key: '5',
  render: (record) => {
    return(
      <>
      <EditOutlined onClick={()=>{
        onEditItems(record)
      }}/>
      <DeleteOutlined onClick={()=>{
        onDeleteItems(record)
      }} style={{color:"red", marginLeft:12}}/>
        </>
    );
    }
},
];
```